How to implement fling gesture in ViewPager2
I have a viewpager2 implemented with a recyclerview adapter.
class SomeAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeAdapter.SliderViewHolder>() {

    private var items = ArrayList<Long>()

    fun addItems(list: ArrayList<Long>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SomeViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        return SomeViewHolder(ItemSomeBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val image = items[position]
        return holder.bind(image)
    }

    inner class SomeViewHolder(private val bind: ViewDataBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bind.root) {

        fun bind(item: Model) {
           // do something
        }
    }
}

I want to be able to have a fling gesture on this.
Because of the nature of my ui I need to be use a ViewPager2 as the main layout.
